# Unable to connect to SSH server with cloud 9

Tags: cloud9-ide, digital-ocean

I've got a digital ocean VPS which I'd like to connect to with Cloud 9's code editor. They have a simple form, which I filled out with the fill out with the required information:

hostname: xxx.xxx.xx.xx
username: stephen
nodejs binary path: /usr/bin/nodejs
Your SSH key: mYpUbLicKey...uploaded through cloud 9's interface
initial path: (optional--I've left blank)
port: (optional--I've left blank)

I get the following error:
Cloud9 couldn't connect to SSH server stephen@xxx.xxx.xx.xx

It's on the default port and allows access to the stephen user (although I tried the above with "root" user and still no dice). Is there something I'm missing here? I tried the exact same commands on the Secure Shell chrome app and I'm able to access the server just fine.

Also I was able to get this to work doing, I believe the exact same thing, but then I realized that I should probably not be doing everything using the root user (I'm a little new at this) so I created the stephen user and changed the information in order to use that user instead. That's when it stopped working. Is it possible that I've given inadvertedly denied access to cloud9 by adding this additional user.

I should also add that I've followed the instructions in cloud9's documentation edited the authorized keys on the server to include the public key that's stored on cloud9.

Any ideas? I know it might be difficult to know what the problem is here, but if someone had an idea at least about where to look, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you didn't add the ssh key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in the homedir of the stephen user?

Comment: No, I double checked just to make sure, there's two sets of public keys in the authorized_keys, exactly the same in the /home/stephen/.ssh as in the /home/root/.ssh directory. This makes sense because I'm able to ssh into the digital ocean box via secure shell I just can't seem to be able to hook up cloud9 to it.

Comment: Hi Stephen, could you send a message via https://c9.io/support ? I have seen this issue before and we need to investigate.

Comment: We troubleshooted it and weren't able to figure it out in the end. Ended up doing it on a new digital ocean droplet and it worked. I will say that at some point I was using two different sets of keys for different things. The above answer is reasonably likely to be the issue so I think it's worth accepting.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this without creating a new instance? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue even after following the instructions on the documentation. Make sure you're allowing SSH from 0.0.0.0/0 onto port 22 for the EC2 instance.